# get heap-use-after-free in Leetcode

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, free

I have a Leetcode problem, No.142, Linked List Cycle II. My code just likes this:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
struct ListNode *detectCycle(struct ListNode *head) {

    struct ListNode *flag = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    int count = 0;

    while (head != NULL) {

        if (head -> next == flag) {
            free(flag);
            return head -> val;
        }

        head -> val = count;
        ++count;

        struct ListNode *p = head;
        head = head -> next;
        p -> next = flag;

    }

    free(flag);
    return -1;

}
```

After I run, I get heap-use-after-free error. How can I fix it?

Comment: After I check each node, I'll change it's NEXT to FLAG and VAL to index(also count). If there is a cycle, head -> next will be FLAG. In that case, I can return the val.

Comment: You are modifying the list with `p->next = flag` which you shouldn't do. And `flag` doesn't change inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a temp variable to stored head->val before flag is free, then return val, see code below.

```
if (head -> next == flag) {
    int val = head->val;    
    free(flag);
    return val;
}
```

Only two places in your code, that your're freeing memory.
I'm only addressing the error you're getting.  I would modify the code to have a single return & free statement, by doing the following:

```
  int returnVal = -1;
  while loop  {

   if (head -> next == flag) {
    returnVal = head->val;
     break;     //exit while loop
   } else  {

     .
     .
     .
 
   }
}     // end while
free(flag);
return returnVal;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Flag is a member of the node. I free the flag, but not the node.